# spark-monitoring library not writing in Azure Log Analytivs Workspace

Tags: azure, apache-spark, logging, databricks

I have installed the new version of the spark-monitoring library which is supposed to support Databricks Runtime 11.0. See here: [spark-monitoring-library](https://github.com/florent-brosse/spark-monitoring). I have successfully attached the init script to my cluster. However, when I run jobs on this cluster, I do not see any logs of the Databricks jobs in Log Analytics. Does anyone have the same problem and has it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

clone
[this](https://github.com/datakickstart/spark-monitoring) git repository using:

```
git clone git@github.com/datakickstart/spark-monitoring.git
```

Import the maven project from \src folder and activate single Maven profile that corresponds to the versions of the Scala/Spark combination that is being used. By default, the Scala 2.12 and Spark 3.0.1 profile is active.

Execute the Maven package phase in your Java IDE to build the JAR files.

Install Databricks CLI.
Create a directory in azure Databricks using Databricks cli
using below command:

```
dbfs mkdirs dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring
```

[image]

Create Log analytics workspace and copy the workspace id and key

[image]

[image]

Open the **/src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh** script file and add Log Analytics Workspace ID and Key.

```
 LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID={id}
 LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_KEY={key}
```

Add above them to environment variable in cluster configuration

[image]

modify the following environment variables on  **/src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh**. For instance:

```
    export AZ_SUBSCRIPTION_ID={ID}
    export AZ_RSRC_GRP_NAME={resourcegroup}
    export  AZ_RSRC_PROV_NAMESPACE=Microsoft.Databricks
    export AZ_RSRC_TYPE=workspaces
    export AZ_RSRC_NAME={workspacename}
```

copy this **src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh** to the directory which is created using Databricks cli using below code:

```
dbfs cp src/spark-listeners/scripts/spark-monitoring.sh dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring/spark-monitoring.sh
```

CLI to copy all of the jar files from the  **src/target**  folder to the directory which is created using Databricks cli  using below code:

```
dbfs cp --overwrite --recursive src/target/ dbfs:/databricks/spark-monitoring/
```

Otherwise you can add the file in init script in cluster:

[image]

Add it using add button and restart the cluster and run sample job logs can be saved in log analytics workspace.

for more information you can refer [this](https://github.com/datakickstart/spark-monitoring)